# SQL trigger overwrites data in the column

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, database-trigger

I have a problem with trigger created to invoke before insert method.
For example, i have 3 columns in my table and 1 of these columns is inserted by trigger.
When i want to insert all data(into all columns) by myself trigger overwrites data in specified column.
The trigger is specified to invoke before insert command so i though that insert command will overwrite data in column specified in trigger.
Do anyone know how to solve this issue?
Is this possible for me to insert all data by myself when i have created a trigger?

Comment: Yes, that is how triggers work. You can add logic to your trigger so that it does not overwrite non-null values.

Comment: If you would like specific help, please post some code.